# Create custom Argo artifact type

Tags: argo-workflows

Whenever an S3 artifact is used, the following declaration is needed:

```yaml
s3:
  endpoint: s3.amazonaws.com
  bucket: "{{workflow.parameters.input-s3-bucket}}"
  key: "{{workflow.parameters.input-s3-path}}/scripts/{{inputs.parameters.type}}.xml"
  accessKeySecret:
    name: s3-access-user-creds
    key: accessKeySecret
  secretKeySecret:
    name: s3-access-user-creds
    key: secretKeySecret
```

It would be helpful if this could be abstracted to something like:

```yaml
custom-s3:
  bucket: "{{workflow.parameters.input-s3-bucket}}"
  key: "{{workflow.parameters.input-s3-path}}/scripts/{{inputs.parameters.type}}.xml"
```

Is there a way to make this kind of custom definition in Argo to reduce boilerplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given Argo installation, you can [set a default artifact repository](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/master/docs/configure-artifact-repository.md#configure-the-default-artifact-repository) in the workflow controller's configmap. This will allow you to only specify the `key` (assuming you set everything else in the default config - if not everything is defined for the default, you'll need to specify more things).

Unfortunately, that will only work if you're only using one S3 config. If you need multiple configurations, cutting down on boilerplate will be more difficult.

In response to your specific question: not exactly. You can't create a custom `some-keyname` (like `custom-s3`) as a member of the `artifacts` array. The exact format of the YAML is defined in Argo's [Workflow Custom Resource Definition](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/master/manifests/base/crds/full/argoproj.io_workflows.yaml). If your Workflow YAML doesn't match that specification, it will be rejected.

However, you can use external templating tools to populate boilerplate *before* the YAML is installed in your cluster. I've used Helm before to do exactly that with a collection of S3 configs. At the simplest, you could use something like `sed`.

tl;dr - for one S3 config, use default artifact config; for multiple S3 configs, use a templating tool.